# Is there a JavaScript/jQuery library to handle auto-direction of input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, bidi

I am looking for a jQuery library to help with handling bidirectionality

Google has one in the closure library, but I feel it is a waste to include all of the library just for bidi input support (unless you recommend me otherwise)
http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/bidiinput.html

the google closure library is a seemingly endless collection for files, with many dependencies. I don't see how using it for 1 function is efficient

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/

**update**

I found [this](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_bidi) from a drupal project. I am unable to make it work. Anyone know of it?

**update2**

it seems that adding "`dir=auto`" to the input field handles it.
works in chrome and ff. anyone can confirm this?

Comment: The file is only 4.8KB... You can take that down even more [by minifying it](http://jscompress.com/) to 1.6KB... Is this really too much for you to include on your page?

Comment: what file did you check. the base.js is 50k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir=auto` should fix it.

it is in the html5 standard, although safari doesn't work with it

http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/new-bidi-xhtml/qa-html-dir

works with chrome and firefox.

Thanks me :)